# The correct syntax of foreach inside a list

Tags: flutter, dart

Why does this code work?

```
child: Column(
  children: 
  [
    for (dynamic answer in answersToQuestion) 
      Row(
        children: [
          Checkbox(
            activeColor: Style.primaryColor,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                answerControllers[question["id"]][answer["libelle"]] = value;
              });
            },
            value: answerControllers[question["id"]][answer["libelle"]],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: FlatButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  answerControllers[question["id"]][answer["libelle"]] = !answerControllers[question["id"]][answer["libelle"]];
                });
              },
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text(
                  answer["libelle"],
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                ),
              )
            )
          ) 
        ],
      ),
    ],
  )
);
```

But, this one does not work at all?

```
child: Column(
  children: 
  [
    for (dynamic answer in answersToQuestion) {
      Row(
        children: [
          Checkbox(
            activeColor: Style.primaryColor,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                answerControllers[question["id"]][answer["libelle"]] = value;
              });
            },
            value: answerControllers[question["id"]][answer["libelle"]],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: FlatButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  answerControllers[question["id"]][answer["libelle"]] = !answerControllers[question["id"]][answer["libelle"]];
                });
              },
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text(
                  answer["libelle"],
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                ),
              )
            )
          ) 
        ],
      ),
    }
  ],
));
```

I added square brackets to the `foreach`, and it did not change anything, but the second code does not work, What is the logic?

I believe that `foreach () { justOne }` and `foreach ()  justOne` are the same. If not, why?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that a code block can be made of a single line or multiple lines: in the latter, you have to surround the code lines with curly braces so the compiler knows that the whole code inside the braces must be treated as a single block.
Take this example:

```
if (something) {
   print(stuff);
   save();
   setState((){});
}
```

If `something` is true, the whole code in the braces is executed because of the braces

```
if (something) 
   print(stuff);
   save();
   setState((){});
```

In this example, if `something` is true only the `print` will be executed, because (usually) the `if` condition executes only the first code block that follows, and in this case the block is made only of `print`, while the other two lines get executed regardless of `something` value.
The code formatting and indentation helps a lot in understanding this: in fact, the second example is often formatted in another way, just to be more understandable:

```
if (something) print(stuff);
save();
setState((){});
```

In this specific case, **you're in the middle of a widget declaration, and this means that code blocks must always be made of single code lines**, so your second piece of code throws error.

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same, actually the `for (dynamic variable in myList)` syntax is kinda new, that helped us to improve an old fashion way of mapping list elements in new classes instances.

To give you an example

Imagine you have a class Test

```
class Test {
  String name;
  
  Test({ required this.name });
  
  @override
  String toString() {
    return this.name;
  }
}
```

And you have a list of names:

```
const names = ['hey', 'test', 'op'];
```

Before Dart 2.3 the only way that you could map your List into class instances (Or Widgets in Flutter) was the following:

```
final list1 = names.map((name) => Test(name: name)).toList();  print(list1); // [hey, test, op]
```

Now you can do this (Your current approach):

```
final list2 = [for (String name in names) Test(name: name)];
print(list2) // [hey, test, op]
```

And if you add brackets, as it's a pretty special syntax, Dart can take it in non-expected way

```
final list3 = [for (String name in names) {
  Test(name: name)
}];

print(list3); // [{hey}, {test}, {op}]
```

And, actually, the type of `list3` is `List<Set<String>>`, that is not a `List<String>`, and Flutter's properties usually work under the type of `List<Widget>`.

Hope that this helps a bit to understand this behavior, but I invite you to play around a bit in Dart Pad:)